# Run a file .exe in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a test driving project, about driving theory test. I have some files which are .exe about crossroads priority ilustartions. Is there any way in Laravel to open this kind of files in a Laravel Project.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to execute files, but my guess is that's not enough for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some possibilities. You can use very simple the `exec` functions in PHP. Or you can use

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

The process component from Symfony to abstract that process. I think there are some more libs that can handle that but the process component is very good.